# What statistical test to use for multiple variables?

Tags: spss

I am trying to find out what test should I use to prove or not if There is positive and significant relationship between consumers’ environmental values/awareness and consumers’ view on Coca-Cola and Pepsi.

In order to do so I use the responses I got from a questionnaire, they are all categorical data

question 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, relates to the consumers' environmental values and question 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 relates to consumers' view on Coca-Cola and Pepsi.

That is quite a lot of variables, therefore I don't know what test to use with SPSS!! anyone could help please?

Many thanks,

Comment: Welcome to the site. First, questions about code are off topic here, so if you just want SPSS code, you need to ask elsewhere. But it seems like there is a statistics question here, but it's unclear. My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you formulate it so it can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You might construct a multidimensional contingency table and test for independence of the two groups of variables. I do not know SPSS. Canonical correlation would also be an option for continuous variables, which is not the case.